# Android Retrofit - How to seperate classes from JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

trying to access JSON data from the following:

```
{"actions":[{"actionType":0,"email":"contact@tonyspizza.com","faIcon":"fa-envelope",
"name":"Contact Us","subject":"Email from Tony's Pizza App"},
{"actionType":2,"faIcon":"fa-phone","name":"Call Us","number":"5204558897"}],
"total":2}
```

I'm trying to use retrofit to access the 'actions' as each individual classes.  (i.e. ActionEmail, ActionPhone, etc).  I cannot figure out a way to separate these into separate classes and not have one class with all the properties.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: R u using any Json parser like Gson with retrofit?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/) out.

Comment: Yes, I am using Gson w/ Retrofit.  It's wanting to place all data under one action class, but my goal is to create an individual class based on each action type.

I.e.: For actionType = 0, it would use an ActionEmail class, for actionType = 2, it would use ActionCall, etc...  

Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Call<ActionWrapperObject> getActions(// Put your api call body in there);
```

Here is your `ActionWrapperObject`

```
public class ActionWrapperObject {
    ArrayList<ActionModel> actions;

    public ArrayList<ActionModel> getActions() {
        return actions;
    }

    public void setActions(ArrayList<ActionModel> actions) {
        this.actions = actions;
    }
}
```

Here is your `ActionModel`

```
public class ActionModel {

    int actionType;
    String email;
    String faIcon;
    String name;
    String subject;

    public int getActionType() {
        return actionType;
    }

    public void setActionType(int actionType) {
        this.actionType = actionType;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFaIcon() {
        return faIcon;
    }

    public void setFaIcon(String faIcon) {
        this.faIcon = faIcon;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}
```

You in your response

```
Your api call.enqueue(new Callback<ActionWrapperObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ActionWrapperObject> call, Response<ActionWrapperObject> response) {
                        ActionWrapperObject actionWrapperObj= response.body();
                        if (actionWrapperObj!= null) {
                          ArrayList<ActionModel> actionModelList= actionWrapperObj.getActions();
//Here you got the list of actions. Do what ever you want with them. You can 
// differentiate each action on its type.
                                                    }
                    }
```

Comment: This is good, and I have implemented a similar solution.  However, this is also based on merely 2 ActionTypes....  what if I want to increase the amount of ActionTypes?  Wouldn't this class become massive?  It just looks wrong when it starts to grow to numerous actionTypes...

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

What I infer is you want to generate fields of the ActionModel class dynamically. You can refer to generating JSON pojo dynamically using reflection.